# Rails class-table inheritance gem, faux-inheritance, and missing methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-table-inheritance

I'm working on modifying part of an existing Rails app to use the Class-Table-Inheritance gem (https://github.com/brunofrank/class-table-inheritance).  All's well, except that I have defined some instance methods in my superclass -- Person, which all subclasses need to be able to access. For instance, `full_name`, which returns the concatenated first and last names, or `cite_name`, which returns the first initial and last name.  Since the CTI gem doesn't actually use Ruby inheritance (all subclasses still inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, and the gem does some funky voodoo to link the ActiveRecord fields together),  I can't access these methods in the subclasses I've created.  Any thoughts on working around this? I'm not interested in STI, but I'm willing to either fork and hack on this particular CTI gem, or look at other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http://peterhamilton.github.com/citier, it's based on CITIEsForRAILS, I forked it & put it through rapid development and various other changes. It fixes most, if not all the bugs it had and works so simply.

Comment: And please let me know how you get on, would love to know everyone else's experiences!

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, did you see that in the migration tables of your subclasses you need to have the line:

```
create_table :videos, :inherits => :product do |t|
```

and also in your Model.rb files

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_superclass # I'm guessing you might be missing this line??
  end

  class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    inherits_from :product
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the brand new CITIEsForRAILS gem (Class Inheritance & Table Inheritance EmbeddingS For RAILS, see https://github.com/altrabio/CITIEsForRAILS ) does exactly what you desire. This gem extends CTI, STI, & Multi Table Inheritance while preserving Ruby class Inheritance.